# How do I prevent unlocked cells from being selected/editable? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a very specific question that I am looking for help in answering. I have been researching for hours and I feel like I am not able to find what I am looking for. Below is a quick overview of the criteria that my document must follow:

- I am using Excel 2013
- I will just be using rows for data input (instead of an excel object
  table).
- The very top/first row will act as my "column header".
- This top row will have AutoFilter enabled.
- THE DOCUMENT MUST BE PROTECTED (a must-have)!
- I will be using VBA code

Now, the final issue I am having with finishing this document are the last two criteria points that I must have:

- The first/top row (column headers) must **NOT BE EDITABLE**.
- Each column must be able to **SORT AND FILTER**.

Now, in a perfect world, I would just "Lock Cells" for the entire first row that acts as my column headers and when I protect the worksheet I would make sure to check the "Sort" and "Use AutoFilter" boxes.

However, this option does not work because there seems to be an issue when I try to sort the data. If I just filter the data there is no problem, but when I try to sort a column in ascending/descending order I will get an error informing me that I can't sort locked cells while in Protected mode. This is because when excel uses the Sort function, it counts the header as part of the data that is being sorted (I found this out through my research) even though I really just want the data below it to be sorted.

I have been trying to brainstorm on how to get past this issue as well as researching different methods, and I am having trouble coming to a final conclusion. However I have narrowed it down to 2 possible solutions:

1. I want to be able to keep the cells in the first row officially **unlocked** to allow the AutoFilter's sort command to work as intended, but make it "behave" like the cells are **locked** when a user tries to make changes to it (AKA, make the entire row un-editable or un-selectable).
2. The other option would be to keep the first row **locked** but somehow have an event in VBA that can tell when a user tries to "Sort" the column, which will then temporarily unprotect the worksheet, follow through with the intended sort command, then protect the worksheet again (apparently though, upon my research there is no such event that can trigger off the AutoFilter's sort command alone).

These 2 solutions are the most logical I can think of based off my research, but if someone out there is an Excel genius and knows another way I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions,

Travo

Comment: Keep your data on another sheet and lock it.  Create another sheet to display the data.  When filter/sort is triggered, copy the data from your locked sheet and just filter/sort.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **two** header rows.  The top row would be protected and the second row would facilitate filtering and sorting of the data in rows 3 and below.